# Is it possible to keep java application and its database in removable disk? if yes how?

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I have simple java standalone application. I want to keep both java application and database(whichever) in pen drive or removable disk.

Is it possible?

if yes please guide me how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely. You can do that.
Keep your executale on Pendrive and configure db path accordingly in code. As long as you connect your pendrive to machine having working JRE and sufficient access rights to folder's it should work. You can have JRE on your pendrive also.

As suggested by @Fidor , see [self-contained-packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html)

Comment: sure. would work. but it would also assume minimal requirements of the jre installed, ...

Comment: @Stultuske yes i agree

Comment: Thank you @Dark Knight. which database is suitable in this case without installing on os (independent)?.

Comment: @DarkKnight You could even use your "own" JRE that you put on the stick as well. Some extra space and effort, but not relying on a installed JRE. See [self-contained-packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html)

Comment: @Fildor Good Point

Comment: @Fildor This is what exactly I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NageshMadale You're welcome. I won't put it as an answer, though, because it would rather be link-only ... If DarkKnight happens to include the hint in his answer, you may accept it maybe.